# Kiel Volapüko influis Esperanton?

Tags: history

Antaŭ la kreado de Esperanto jam ekzistis planlingvo nomata Volapük. Post la eldono de la Unua Libro, multaj Volapükkluboj iĝis Esperantaj kluboj.

Sed kiel Volapüko influis Esperanton? Ĉu oni uzas kelkajn gramatikajn heredaĵojn de ĝi senscie de multaj hodiaŭaj E-parolantoj? Kion oni lernis de Volapüko por ne fari la samajn erarojn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En la libro Menade Bal Püki Bal (volapuka titolo sed kun artikoloj en la germana kaj en Esperanto) estas interesa artikolo de Geraldo Mattos kun la titolo "La Polapüka Esperanto". La ĉefa temo estas la praEsperanto de 1881, kaj ĝi detale esploras la influon kaj de la pola lingvo kaj de volapuko sur tiu praEsperanto. En la fino estas diskuto pri la influo de volapuko sur la Esperanto de 1887. Estas ekzemple interesa diskuto pri la vorto “ol”. Se tiu temo estas interesa al vi, mi rekomendas ke vi aĉetu kaj legu la libron.

Pri volapükkluboj (ekzemple la klubo en Nurenbergo) kiuj transiris de volapuko al Esperanto, en la libro Esperanto Sen Mitoj ziko rekomendis ne rakonti tiun historion ĉar (laŭ Ziko) ili ne nur transiris al Esperanto, sed poste al Ido, Interlingue, ktp. Jen mallonga interŝanĝo inter mi kaj Don Harlow pri tiu temo.

https://listserv.brown.edu/archives/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0506C&L=AUXLANG&F=&S=&P=7426

Subject: Re: IAL Death

From:"Donald J. HARLOW"

Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2005 18:28:43 -0700

Je 06.08 ptm 2005.06.15, Thomas ALEXANDER skribis

> Don Harlow wrote:
>
> > (The first local Esperanto society was the former
> >      World Language [Volapuk] society in Nurnberg,
> >     which gave up on Volapuk at about this time.)
>
> Is there any truth to the story (as reported in
>   "Esperanto Sen Mitoj") that this Nurnberg group was
>   basically just following the flavor of the day - and
>   after jumping ship from Vp to Eo, jumped on to several
>   other ships after that?

I think Ziko may have been guessing at their motivations, but I believe
that at least part of the group did move on. However, probably not all,
since today's Nurnberg Esperanto group at least claims to be the direct
descendant of that original group (they celebrated their centennial in
1988, if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 8):

Volapuko ne estis vidita detale de Zamenhof, ĝi ne tro multe influis la lingvon. Tamen multaj aferoj sufiĉe similas inter ili kaj diversaj kritikoj nuntempaj pri Esperanto fakte jam estis solvitaj en Volapuko.

Kion ni lernis de ĝi estas ekzemple ke gravas uzi internaciajn vortojn por faciligi la lernadon kaj ke ne necesas havi tiom vastan gramatikon por havi funkciantan lingvon. Ankaŭ ke facileco de prononco gravas, precipe pri vokaloj. Tamen estas malmultaj veraj kritikoj fareblaj al Volapuko ekster tio.

Interesaj heredaĵoj tamen estas ekzemple la plej malnova Esperanto-klubo, tiu de Nurenbergo kiu ŝanĝis de Volapuko al Esperanto en 1888, kaj kelkaj fruaj Esperanto-aŭtoroj unue estis Volapukistoj.